# NET CORE 3.1 OpenIdConnect Redirect

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, keycloak, .net-core-3.1

I can't find an example of how to control the redirect after a successful login to an OpenIdConnect Identity Provider.  It always redirects me back to the original request that started the Authorize challenge.  Which may be great in some standard setups, but I'm behind a reverse proxy.

User -> Reverse Proxy -> App

When user attempts to request [Authorize] endpoint they are redirected to KeyCloak Identity Provider login.  Then they are redirected back to original request.  However the original request is behind the Reverse Proxy and therefore fails.  I need to modify the 'redirect_uri' so that it instead points to the Reverse Proxy domain:port.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Same as this question and answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60551201/how-to-access-keycloak-endpoints-via-proxy-api