# How to access KeyCloak endpoints via proxy API

Tags: api, oauth, proxy, openid-connect, keycloak

I currently have the following architecture

APP -> API -> KeyCloak

I want the APP to be able to send requests to my API which will then internally proxy certain requests to KeyCloak.  For example, I'd like to make a request to the /userinfo endpoint in KeyCloak through my API.  If I can figure this out I can then perform more complex features.

APP -> http://api:port/api/userinfo
API -> http://keycloak:port/auth/realms/quartech/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo

I have a valid JWT Bearer token.  As I can directly make the request to KeyCloak successfully, however if I attempt to make the request via my API it returns 401.  Even though it is using the same JWT Bearer token.

I believe it has something to do with configuring the KeyCloak client to allow requests to come from the API.  But so far I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I've added the following headers to the API proxy request and it still doesn't work.

Authorization: Bearer [token]

X-Forwarded-For: [original host]

X-Forwarded-Proto: [original scheme]

X-Forwarded-Port: [original port]

ProxyPreserveHost: On

Comment: When I started using proxy/load balancer I have to add `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` for my Keycloak docker container. Here is documentation that may be useful:
[Setting Up a Load Balancer or Proxy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered it required a DNS entry to local development within a Docker container.

I've edited the `hosts` file and added a `127.0.0.1 keycloak` and then al